# PHPExcel RichText Excel5 Office 2007 complains at error

Tags: php, phpexcel

I've tried to use RichText and mostly it works fine but sometimes (one case to 20) Microsoft Offices fails to open certain documents saying that they are broken.

The code is:

```
                    $objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
                $objRichText->createTextRun("Руководитель   ")
                      ->getFont()->setSize($textSize);
                $objRichText->createTextRun("    Иванов Петр Анатольевна     ")
                      ->getFont()->setSize($textSize)
                      ->setUnderline(PHPExcel_Style_Font::UNDERLINE_SINGLE);
                $sheet->mergeCells("B$i:F$i")
                      ->setCellValue("B$i", $objRichText);
```

If I replace RichText with usual text it works  100% fine  in all cases.

The code is:

```
 $sheet->getStyle("B$i")->getFont()->setBold(true);
                    $sheet->setCellValue("B$i", 'Руководитель ');

                    $styleArray = array('font' => array('bold' => false, 'underline' => PHPExcel_Style_Font::UNDERLINE_SINGLE),);

                    $sheet->getStyle("C$i")->applyFromArray($styleArray);
                    $sheet->mergeCells("C$i:F$i")->setCellValue("C$i",
                          '  Иванов Пётр Анатольевна');
```

I would be glad to leave RichText. But I can't because client would like to have differently formatted text in the same cell.

Looks like it has something in common with https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/284 
Any ideas why it happens so?

Comment: someone voted to close? please explain why

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by switching to Excel2007 instead of Excel5.

Still looking for solution with Excel5